# The session contents do not appear in the content of the second page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, session

I put this sessions in the page load of the page I want them to be displayed in, but the session contents appear in the top of my website not in the content what is the problem????

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Response.Write("<h1 align=center>Radiation Calculator</h1>")
    Response.Write("<br>Hi Mr/Mrs " & Session("Username"))
    Response.Write("<br>The following results have been sent to your Email " & Session("Email"))
    Response.Write("<br>Air Traveling Distance " & Session("Air Traveling Disance") & " Km")
    Response.Write("<br>You have selected the following Factors: " & Session("Factor0") & " . " & Session("Factor1") & " . " & Session("Factor2") & " . " & Session("Factor3") & " . " & Session("Factor4") & " . " & Session("Factor5") & " . " & Session("Factor6") & " . " & Session("Factor7"))
    Response.Write("<br>Total Radiation " & Session("Total Radiation") & " mrem")
    Response.Write("<br>Your Life Reduction would be: " & Session("User Life Expectancy In Minutes") & "Mintues " & "  " & Session("User Life Expectancy In Hours"))



End Sub
```

Comment: "Urgent Please" --- this is terrible way to start your question here. You must be missed stackoverflow.com and odesk.com/rentacoder.com

Comment: welcome to SO! We do not "erase" questions when they are resolved here. That way, they may help future searchers.

Answer (score 3):

Its because you write directly in the response stream for the client. So everything you write at Page Load is written before anything else. Please see the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for informations when specific methods are called.

But in the most cases you don't have to (and should not do) write directly in the Response. Modify your aspx-File, so you have server-side controls for your stuff, like:

> ```
> <h1 align="center">Radiation Calculator</h1>
> <br>Hi Mr/Mrs <asp:Label id="lblUsername" runat="server" />
> ...
> ```

And than use in the Page_Load method:

> ```
> lblUsername.Text = Session("Username")
> ```

So forget about the Response.Write. Modify your ASPX-Page so you have regular HTML inside it. Use server-side controls for your content and then assign the proper values to your controls int he Page_Load method in code behind.

Comment: That is not a real exact statement. How do you solved your problem now and whats the error?